# ESLint Unable to resolve path to module 'react-router-dom'. (import/no-unresolved)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting this error as of today. The weird this is it had never happened before and the same error persists with the relative paths as well. 
Header.js file which gives the error

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logout from './User/Logout';

const Header = ({ title }) => (
  <div className="title-bar">
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
    {Meteor.userId() ? <Logout /> :
    <div className="dropdown">
      <Link to="/login" className="button header__navigation">Login</Link>
      <Link to="/signup" className="button header__navigation">Signup</Link>
      <Link to="/about" className="button header__navigation">About</Link>
      <Link to="/How" className="button header__navigation">How it Works</Link>
      <Link to="/tos" className="button header__navigation">Terms of Service</Link>
    </div>
  }
  </div>
);

Header.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Header;
```

Here is my .eslintrc.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb',
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'jsx-a11y',
    'import',
    'meteor'
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'react/require-extension': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { devDependencies: true }],
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
    'comma-dangle': ['error', { functions: 'ignore' }],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off'
  },
  settings: {
    'import/core-modules': ['meteor/meteor', 'meteor/tracker', 'meteor/mongo', 'meteor/react-meteor-data', 'meteor/accounts-base']
  },
  env: {
    mocha: true,
    browser: true
  }
};
```

Comment: `react-router-dom` isn't even mentioned in your eslint file. Could it be you updated your packages and it introduced the dependency on the package?

Comment: I have actually just understood the problem. I had accessed into the folder by typing `Desktop` , rather than using `desktop` as i normally do. I changed back to desktop/myapp folder and the errors were gone. Is it a normal behaviour ?